# Read filename in Grunt task

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, gruntjs, rename

I've got Grunt set up to use grunt-replace so that I can find a div in a few hundred HTML pages, and replace the text within the div with the current filename of the HTML file it's in. I'm not sure exactly how to do this however. I tried using `window.loacation.href` but this just generates an error when I run the task.

Here is my Gruntfile.coffee:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON "package.json"
    gruntfile: "Gruntfile.coffee"

    replace:
        dist:
            options:
                patterns: [
                    match: "<div id'name_goes_here'></div>"
                    replacement: ->
                        "<div id'name_goes_here'>Filename: #{window.location.href}</div>"
                ]
            usePrefix: false
            files: [
                expand: true
                flatten: true
                src: [
                    "src/*.html"
                ],
                dest: "output/"
            ]

grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-replace";
grunt.registerTask "default", ["replace"];
```

Just as a side note, I've tried passing in a variable containing a simple string into the replacement string and this works and replaces it all the HTML pages, so the Grunt task is definitely working. And also the reason replacement is a function is because I plan on adding some extra things in later, but just want to get this working for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated regex in `Gruntfile.js` to handle `<div>` tags that may also include attributes in addition to the `id` only. For example:

```html
<!-- Also includes a class -->
<div id="QUUX" class="foo">...</div>
```

---

Firstly `grunt` runs on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), so calling `window.location.href` will produce an error as the `.html` files to be processed are not loaded into a web browser. `window.location.href` is a convention of the [BOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms952643.aspx), and typically only works within browser environments.

[grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace) with standard Task configuration(s) does not provide a mechanism to obtain the filename being processed. However, as `grunt-replace` is a [multi-task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks) plugin, your requirement can be met by utilizing a custom function to dynamically create the `replace` Task object.

---

The following shows how this can be achieved:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig( {
    replace: {} // <-- // Intentionally empty, will be generated dynamically.
  });

  /**
   * Helper function dynamically creates config object for `replace` Task.
   * We dynamically generate this to obtain the filename and use that for
   * the `replacement` value.
   */
  function replaceHtml() {
    var glob = 'src/*.html',
      config = {};

    grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isFile' }, glob).forEach(function (filePath) {
      var fileName = filePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
      config[fileName] = {
        options: {
          usePrefix: false,
          patterns: [{
            // Regex pattern explained here: https://regex101.com/r/uJVMOI/3
            match: /(<div.*?id=\"QUUX\".*?>)[\s\S]+?(<\/div>)/g,
            replacement: '$1' + fileName + '$2'
          }]
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: filePath,
          dest: 'output/'
        }]
      }
    });

    grunt.config('replace', config);
    grunt.task.run(['replace']);
  }

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace');
  grunt.registerTask("default", replaceHtml);
};
```

---

**Notes**

1. The configuration for the `replace` Task is intentionally set to an empty object.
2. The `replaceHtml` function utilizes [grunt.file.expand](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) to loop over each file found via the [glob](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) pattern `'src/*.html'`.
3. The `fileName` variable is obtained via the current `filePath`.
4. During each loop of the `forEach` statement a [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) is generated and added to the `config` object.
5. When exiting the `forEach` loop the `config` object is added to the `replace` Task/Object by utlizing [grunt.config](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config), before finally calling [grunt.task.run](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run)

**Regex**

So whats the following part doing ?

```js
patterns: [{
  match: /(<div.*?id=\"QUUX\".*?>)[\s\S]+?(<\/div>)/g,
  replacement: '$1' + fileName + '$2'
}]
```

The `match` part utilizes a regular expression which is further explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/uJVMOI/3). It currently searches for instances of:

```html
<div id="QUUX">...</div>
```

So, lets say the snippet above resides in a file named `index.html` - then the resultant file will read:

```html
<div id="QUUX">index</div>
```

However, if in the resultant file it should read (i.e. it should include the file suffix `.html`):

```html
<div id="QUUX">index.html</div>
```

...then you'll need to change the assignment of the `fileName` variable on line no. 17 in the `Gruntfile.js` to:

```js
var fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
```

**Multiple matches**

To perform multiple matches simply add another pattern Object to the `patterns` Array. For example:

```js
// ...
patterns: [{
  match: /(<div.*?id=\"QUUX\".*?>)[\s\S]+?(<\/div>)/g,
  replacement: '$1' + fileName + '$2'
}, {
  match: /(<div.*?id=\"FOOBAR\".*?>)[\s\S]+?(<\/div>)/g,
  replacement: '$1' + fileName + '$2'
}]
// ...
```

Lets say the file being processed is named `hello-world.html` - then the example above will replace any instances of

```html
<div class="foo" id="QUUX">...</div>
```

or

```html
<div id="FOOBAR" class="foo">...</div>
```

with

```html
<div class="foo" id="QUUX">hello-world</div>
```

and

```html
<div id="FOOBAR" class="foo">hello-world</div>
```

respectively.